# Unable to access Windows after installing Ubuntu on 2nd drive

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot

I had a spare drive laying around, so I decided to plug it into my Windows 10 desktop and install ubuntu onto it. While selecting the desired Ubuntu installation mode I chose erase disk and install Ubuntu and selected the extra empty drive. Everything went well and I got Ubuntu installed.

Now comes the problem. I don't see my Windows 10 installation in BIOS or GRUB. I've tried `os-prober` and `update-grub` with no success. After unplugging the Ubuntu drive, I get booted straight to the BIOS.

PS: I still see all my filed on the Windows 10 drive, it didn't get formated or anything.

How can I repair the Windows 10 drive?

Comment: There are 2 installation modes: UEFI (for anything since 2012 with UEFI instead of BIOS) and Legacy (emulates the old BIOS and, of course, the only mode available for old computers with BIOS). If your Windows (8 or newer) was preinstalled then it's surely UEFI mode. If you installed Ubuntu in Legacy mode then you won't be able to dual-boot with Grub.

Comment: Sorry I've should have clarified. It was Windows 10. Are there any steps to repair this?

Comment: We don't know what you actually did / what's the actual situation right now. If Windows was installed in the proper mode then it must show up in UEFI ("BIOS") settings > Boot menu.

Comment: I've already mentioned this in the OG question. The drive containing Win10 does not show up in BIOS. Something during the Ubuntu install must've broken it.

Comment: Clearly you don't understand UEFI mode if you're thinking about "drives".  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair <- use the 2nd option to install it directly in your Ubuntu, no need to do it from a live session. **Do NOT apply any fix**. Press bootinfo summary which will generate URL then edit the question and add it.

Comment: Installing Ubuntu wouldn’t have changed the boot mode, but can you verify, if CSM is enabled or disabled?